# Error importing the Levenshtein package in Racket

Tags: racket

I am trying to use the [Levenshtein](http://www.neilvandyke.org/racket/levenshtein/) package in Racket.

However, even using the "require" command, I still have problems:

```
#lang racket

 (require levenshtein)
>> standard-module-name-resolver: collection not found
  for module path: levenshtein
  collection: "levenshtein"
  in collection directories:
   /home/pedro/.racket/6.6/collects
   /usr/share/racket/collects
   ... [156 additional linked and package directories] in: levenshtein
  no packages suggestions are available .
```

I have already used other packages before, with (require racket/trace) or (require rackunit).

Why this package does not work? What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The packages `racket/trace` and `rackunit` are included in the distribution.
The package `levenshtein` needs to be installed first. An easy way to do this:

```
1) Open DrRacket 
2) In the menu choose "Package Manager..." 
3) Choose the tab "Available from catalog" 
4) Find your package and install it
```

Comment: Alternatively, just run `raco pkg install levenshtein` from the command-line.

Comment: Thanks, apparently, the installation was mostly succesfull. Should I worry about this: raco setup: docs failure: query-exec: unable to open the database file
  error code: 14
  SQL: "ATTACH $1 AS other"
  database: #<path:/home/pedro/.racket/6.6/doc/docindex.sqlite>
  mode: 'read-only
  file permissions: (write read)
raco setup: --- installing collections ---
raco setup: --- post-installing collections ---
drracket install: packages installed, although setup reported errors

Comment: @Harry The package itself is installed correctly. However the installation of the documentation failed. Mostly likely you need to change the permissions of the folder, where the documentation is stored.

Comment: @Harry It might be a bug in the installer. Which installer did you use?

Comment: Btw, that error is something that transiently happens in many situations, but doesn't reflect a problem in your installation.